# CGI and sudoers

Tags: apache-httpd, sudo, script

I may got stuck in a very simple problem, but I can't figure it out.
I would like to run using a cgi script a simple command: `sudo service transmission-daemon stop` in order to stop a system daemon.

I learned to manage the sudo privileges, using `sudo visudo`, and declaring the `www-data` user the access to the folder containing the scripts (in this case, `/var/www/cgi-bin`). At the moment I'm not concerned about security simply because my Raspberry PI isn't accessible externally.

Anyway, I obviously set the script as executable (`sudo chmod +x reboot.cgi`), and the ownership of the script (`sudo chown www-data:www-data reboot.cgi`).

The problem is that simply the script won't succeed, and looking at the `error.log` of apache it says:

```
    [Sun Nov 17 17:09:27 2013] [error] [client 192.168.0.3] sudo, referer: http://mezzopi.local/cgi-bin/info.cgi
[Sun Nov 17 17:09:27 2013] [error] [client 192.168.0.3] : , referer: http://mezzopi.local/cgi-bin/info.cgi
[Sun Nov 17 17:09:27 2013] [error] [client 192.168.0.3] no tty present and no askpass program specified, referer: http://mezzopi.local/cgi-bin/info.cgi
[Sun Nov 17 17:09:27 2013] [error] [client 192.168.0.3] , referer: http://mezzopi.local/cgi-bin/info.cgi
```

It seems that apache is required to have a tty to input the sudo password (isn't it strange in the first place?), although I set using `sudo visudo` the option `Defaults:www-data !requiretty` in order to disable such possibility.

Following is my CGI script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""

echo "<html> <head>"
echo "<title>Transmission</title> </head> <body>"

echo "<table><tr><td>"
echo "<a href=../index.html>Home</a><br>"

echo "<h3>Transmission</h3>"
echo "<pre> $(sudo service transmission-daemon stop) </pre>"

echo "</body></html>"
```

It doesn't work either if I change the daemon to stop, i.e. minidlna or pyLoad.
What I'm missing?

Thanks everyone for your time.

Comment: Try `echo "password"|sudo service transmission-daemon stop`

Comment: Just tried. Didn't work. I am completely lost.

Comment: Create a sh script with `sudo service transmission-daemon stop`, set owner to root (chown), allow all to execute (chmod) and set sticky flag. This will allow all users to start the script, which will run as the admin user -  http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure you want to give the *www-data* group  the ability to restart a service, you should specify the commands within the sudoers file.

```
%www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service SERVICENAME *
```

or

```
%www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service SERVICENAME stop, /usr/sbin/service SERVICENAME start, /usr/sbin/service SERVICENAME restart
```

Note: The *www-data* group is typically reserved for publicly accessible web services and extra care should be taken when giving this group (or any other group) sudo privileges.

Answer (score 0):

the correct way to supply the password to "sudo" command would be:

```
echo <password> | sudo -S service transmission-daemon stop
```

(note the "-S" command line option, that is capital S, not the lowercase one)

Answer (score -1):

I had this exact same problem!

I know and as others have mentioned, this is very bad, but as it's a Pi and the question stated that they wern't worried about security...

I fixed it by putting this in the sudoers file:

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

This basically means that the user www-data doesn't need a password to run sudo.

Comment: This is a very, very bad thing.  The www-data group is typically reserved for untrusted, publicly accessible daemons/servers, such as web (nginx, apache) and torrenting.  You are allowing easy escalation to root.  If you really want to allow someone on the web to restart a service, list the specific commands explicitly, as [shown here](http://askubuntu.com/a/246592/13247).

Comment: I know it is. In fact, I got it slightly wrong, what I have is: `Defaults:www-data !requiretty` and `www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`